# How to take partial derivatives of functions whose inputs depend on the same variable?

Tags: functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, partial-derivative

I am starting to learn about the Calculus of Variations and [the Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Statement) is extremely confusing to me:

> The Euler–Lagrange equation, then, is given by
>   $$L_x(t,q(t),q'(t))-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}L_v(t,q(t),q'(t)) = 0.$$
>   where $L_x$ and $L_v$ denote the partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to the second and third arguments, respectively.

Specifically, I don't understand the meaning of:
$$L_x = \frac{\partial L(t, q, q')}{\partial q}$$

I'm confused because $q$ and $q'$ are **both functions of $t$**, but taking a partial derivative *requires that we hold other parameters constant*.

Yet $t$ is a parameter of $L$ as well. Thus when differentiating $L$ with respect to $q$, we hold $t$ constant.

But if $t$ is constant then doesn't that mean $q$ and $q'$ are constant?
And hence mustn't  the derivatives $L_x$ and $L_v$ both be equal to zero?

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307411/derivative-of-fx-y-with-respect-to-another-function-of-two-variables-kx-y

Comment: @JeffSnider: Thanks, I'm looking at that right now, it seems very relevant indeed.

Comment: I have seen somewhere that you can use the chain rule to reach $$L_x=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}L(t,q,q')}{\frac{d}{dt}q}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we write $L$ as $L(t,q(t),q'(t))$, it is really just a function of three variables. We could just as easily write it as $L(x,y,z)$ and, when evaluating $L$ on a given function $q$, substitute $t$ for $x$, $q(t)$ for $y$, and $q'(t)$ for $z$. However, this could lead to some confusion and lots of extra notation, so it is not usually done.

So, when taking the partial derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$, we can just ignore any relations between $q$ and $q'$ and treat them as totally separate variables.

Comment: +1 ah that makes sense, I get it now! I'll explain it another way in case someone else who sees this will find it helpful (especially if they had a CS background like me): the function $L$ is defined for *any* $q$ and $q'$; the fact that the two are related and functions of $t$ is *not* relevant to the differentiation of $L$ with respect to either of them. When the derivative is *evaluated* at a particular $q$, if the parameters are related, then this will of course matter. But the original derivative does not care about whether or not the three parameters are functions of each other.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps better for CS backgrounds:  $\partial/\partial t \ F(t,x,y)$ means the derivative of the function with respect to variation in its first slot, the formal parameter $t$.  $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d} t\ F(t,x,y)$ means the derivative of the function with respect to the system parameter $t$.  The difference is between local parameter names (partial differentiation) and global variables (total differentiation).