# Differentiating f(x1,x2,x3..xn) w.r.t g(x1,x2,...xm)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate a function $f(x,y,\frac{\partial y}{\partial x},\frac{\partial(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})}{\partial x})$ w.r.t $g(x,y)$ but I am not quite sure how to proceed. I tried following the explanation here- [Derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to another function of two variables $k(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307411/derivative-of-fx-y-with-respect-to-another-function-of-two-variables-kx-y?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I am having a difficulty expanding the idea to my case. In the above case, consider $x$ to be the independent variable.

It would be great if you could also suggest a reference book I can follow.

**EDIT to show specific problem:**

I have a function - 
[F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joyOO.png)
In this n is defined as n = ($cos\theta$$cos\phi$,$cos\theta$$sin\phi$,$sin\theta$). Further, $\theta$ = $\theta(x,y,z)$ and $\phi$ = $\phi(x,y,z)$. I want to evaluate [Derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ruJ.png).

I am presently simulating the flow of nematic liquid crystals using Leslie Ericksen theory. I am adding a screenshot of all the equations of the theory. Essentially, n describes the orientation of a liquid crystal. Depending on the external forces ( may be a flow or magnetic field or an electric field) change orientation to obtain a state with the lowest energy (most stable). [Summary of all equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCN0g.png).

In my actual problem, $(x,y,z)$ are the cartesian coordinates and the others are functions that dependent on them.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: I want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ where f is a function of n variables and g is a function of m variables

Comment: I can read what you wrote, but I have still no idea what it means.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the exact problem.

Comment: I am familiar with derivatives in the usual sense, but there is some context to your problem that I am missing.

Comment: Can you please tell me what sort of information you are looking for?

Comment: A definition of what it means.

Comment: Added the physical basis. I do not know what else I can add

Comment: @copper.hat You are inverting $g$ to obtain new coordinates $y$, then write $f$ in those coordinates and differentiate with respect to $y$.

Comment: @copper.hat, do you have any ideas for the problem I have mentioned?

Comment: @SomBhat: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I don't understand the notation (what is ${\partial y \over \partial x^2}$?). I don't know what $g$ is (what is the range?)

Comment: @copper.hat, I am sorry, that is meant to be the second derivative of y w.r.t x. For my case g is a non-negative real quantity.

Comment: @SomBhat: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do :-(.

Comment: You will need to be a bit more specific, I think. There *is* a sense by which you can differentiate with respect to a function that is not naturally one of the independent variables, if the independent variables are related in some way to the variable with respect to which you want to differentiate.

Comment: (Cont.) For example, if you have $E(S,V)$ and $T=\left ( \frac{\partial E}{\partial S} \right )_V$ (where the subscript means "hold these variables constant"), you can make sense of $\left ( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right )_V$. But it is crucial that you fully specify what is held constant and what isn't. In your case it doesn't seem that you have done so sufficiently.

Comment: @Ian is there more info required for clarity?

Comment: @SomBhat Yes; basically, to differentiate with respect to $g$, you move in some path in the underlying $(x,y)$ space. But you need to say what that path is, which means holding at least one quantity (usually exactly one quantity) constant.

Comment: @Ian, I finally understood what you mean. Referring to the problem I have shown in the Edit, I am evaluating the derivative at a given coordinate $(x,y,z)$. I don't think it is possible to hold all 3 constant (or is it)?