# Can we take the partial derivative of a function $f(x, y, z)$ with respect to $g(x, y, z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

In Calculus 1 we differentiated $f(x)$ with respect to $g(x)$ that is, $\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}$ by using chain rule:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dg(x)}= \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Is there something like this in partial derivatives too? For example:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial g(x,y,z)}$$
where $f(x, y, z)=xyz$ and $g(x, y, z)=x+y+z$

Comment: There is a chain rule for [the multivariable case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiation of one function with respect to another in multivariable calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353862/differentiation-of-one-function-with-respect-to-another-in-multivariable-calculu)

Comment: Consider a function $f(z, y)=z^2y$ where $z=xy$. Thus, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2zy=2xy^2$$ But it is equivalent to saying:$$ \frac{\partial (x^2y^3)}{\partial (xy)}= 2xy^2$$ I'm puzzled here.